# Grails Spring Security Open ID not working

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I've been trying to use the Grails Spring Security OpenID plugin and while following the tutorial instructions https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-openid/docs/manual/guide/tutorials.html it just doesn't work at:

> Navigate to `http://localhost:8080/openidtest/secure/admins` and you should be prompted with the login screen. Leave the Use OpenID checkbox checked and enter a valid OpenID. Don't check the remember-me checkbox yet (it doesn't work with the extended workflows where you create a new user or link an OpenID) and click the "Log in" button.
>
> After authenticating at the OpenID provider, you'll be redirected to the registration page. Note that there's a link to just associate the current OpenID with a local account - for now click the "link this OpenID" link.

When I try to log in, I simply get:

> Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.

The documentation is not recent, and last I saw in some other post was that Burt said he had some github issues and had not been able to updated it (I think it was a stackoverflow comment around October 2013).

Does anyone know if there is a configuration or setting that must be changed? or a new step perhaps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have come to this conclusion from reading a few different sources and trying things out. I stand to be corrected, however, the current solution is working for me.

My humble understanding: The OpenID input in the plugin requests a link from the OpenID Account provider (e.g. google) with which the user will be authenticated.

Websites can just have a link for each provider they want to support instead of asking for a link, so that you would have a "Login with Google" button with the link prefilled (which by the way is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`).

It can help to just look at how other websites do it. You can also just google openid and your provider to find out their links.

Note that some providers have a static link, while it looks like others have user specific links. I'm not yet sure how to deal with user specific links yet.